# Html making a table with vertical columns

Tags: html

I am trying to make a table with vertical columns ,

Is my code makes it how it should implemented ?

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="100%" style="background        color:white;">
<tr>
    <th >Table header</th>
    <td>Table cell 1</td>
    <td>Table cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you looking for multple rows with one column or multiple rows with multiple columns in a table?

Comment: don't get it. What's exactly the problem?

Comment: @JQone multiple columns with multiple rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like below to get multiple rows with multiple columns

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="100%"   
style="background        color:white;">     
<tr>
     <th>Header Name1</th>     
     <th>Header name2</th>     
</tr>     
<tr>         
    <td>Row 1 Column 1</td> 
    <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>     
</tr>    
<tr>         
    <td>Row 2 Column 1</td> 
    <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>     
</tr>    

</table>
```

You have to add a separate tr tag for each row.

Answer (score 1):

To create a table with multiple vertical columns and multiple rows you need to structure your table as a set of `<tr>`'s the first is the table header, each `<td>` in this header is a column header cell and the following `<tr>`'s are the rows like this:

```
 <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="100%" style="background        color:white;">
    <tr>
       <th>Column1</th>
       <th>Column2</th>
       <th>Column3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Row 1 Column 1</td>
       <td>Row 1 Column 2</td>
       <td>Row 1 Column 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
       <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
       <td>Row 2 Column 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MGA088/b8afE/1/)